# Backbone.Model で sync イベントが発火したとき、期待する値が set されていない

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

Backbone.js と Backbone.Marionette の組み合わせで、以下のようなコードを書いています。

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '任意のURL',

    dataFetch: function() {
        this.fetch()
            .fail(alert('error!!'));
    }
});

var ViewItem = Marionette.ViewItem.extend({
    model: new Model();
    modelEvents: {
        'sync': 'displayModelAttr'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.model.dataFetch();
    },

    displayModelAttr: function() {
        console.log(this.model.attributes);
    }
});

var viewItem = new ViewItem();
```

`model` で発火した `sync` イベントで拾い、 `model` の `attributes` をコンソールに表示しています。
しかしながら指定した url から `fetch` した値ではなく、空の Object が表示されてしまいます。
`sync` イベントが発火した時点で、 `model` は `fetch` した結果を自身に `set` していると考えていたのですが、まず、その認識から誤っているのでしょうか。

通信そのものは正常に成功しており、期待したjsonが返却されていることをブラウザの開発ツールで確認しております。

Comment: backbone 1.1.2 のソースを読む限りは、set してから sync イベントをtrigger しているんですよね… それぞれ使っているバージョンを教えてもらえますか?

Comment: Backbone.js は 1.1.2、Backbone.Marionetteは2.3.1 を利用しております。また Backbone.js は Underscore.js に依存していますが、今回は Lo-Dash 2.4.1 を使っております。

Answer (score 1):

問題が再現できないので関係あるか不明ですが、`Marionette.ItemView.extend` で model を を指定するかわりに、`new ViewItem({model: new Model()})` のようにコンストラクタで model を指定するようにしてみてはいかがでしょうか?

元のコードだと、すべての ViewItem で 1 つの model を共有してしまっているために、期待しない挙動になっているのかもしれません。

下記のコードで試したところ、期待通り、サーバから取得した値が表示されました。
質問中のコードからの変更箇所はコメントで示しています。

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "/model.json",
    dataFetch: function() {
        this.fetch()
            .fail(function() { alert('error!!') }); // fail に関数を渡すよう変更
    }
});

var ViewItem = Marionette.ItemView.extend({ // Marionette.ViewItem -> Marionette.ItemView
    // ここで model を指定するとすべての ViewItem で 1 つの model が共有されてしまう
    // コンストラクタに model を渡すよう変更する
    // model: new Model(),
    modelEvents: {
        'sync': 'displayModelAttr'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.model.dataFetch();
    },

    displayModelAttr: function() {
        console.log(this.model.attributes);
    }
});

var viewItem = new ViewItem({model: new Model()}); // ViewItem ごとに異なる model を渡す
```

検証環境:

- jQuery 2.1.3
- Underscore 1.6.0
- Backbone 1.1.2
- Marionette 2.3.1
- Chrome 39